# Waiting for Facebook to review my apps login permissions for 10 weeks. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: facebook, review

I submitted my app for Facebook login permissions review 10 weeks ago to date, and have heard nothing back. I read on their blog that the current wait time could take up to 7 weeks including the business verification.

I am now concerned that my review has got lost in the system due to all of the changes being made to the platform. I have looked everywhere for some way to contact someone at Facebook just to get some clarification but this is the only point of contact I can find.

I don't want to re-submit my app and have to wait another 7 weeks.

Is there anything I can do in this situation?

Comment: Voting to close as a Facebook customer service question. Their help page may have pointed you here, but this kind of question is inappropriate here. We would be able to help with specific use of their API etc.

Comment: Do you know how I can contact their customer service team?

Comment: No, unfortunately. There may be something on the page that lead you here though.